# Why is this getting a syntax error

Tags: python, syntax

I keep getting a syntax error on  the `(turns-=3)` and then also on `else:` .  I thought I set my simple code up correctly.

```
from random import randint

rn=random.randomint(1, 10)

turns=3


while turns>0:
    guess=int(input('Guess a number  '))

    if guess==rn:
        print('YOU WIN!!')
        break

    elif guess!=rn:
        print('Nope, Try Again.'
    turns-=1          
else:
    print('Sorry you are out of turns. You lose, but better luck next time.')
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Use `randint` instead of `random.randomint`

Comment: The specific error is because you don't have a `)` on the print line above the `turns-=1` line. But there are other problems after that.

Comment: Worked wonderfully, thank you very much.

Comment: If my answer helped, please [mark it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific error was because you didn't close the `print` statement with a `)` on the line above. There were also some other problems. I cleaned up your code and this runs for me :

```py
from random import randint

rn=randint(1, 10)

turns=3

while turns>0:
  guess=int(input('Guess a number '))

  if guess==rn:
      print('YOU WIN!!')
      break

  elif guess!=rn:
      print('Nope, Try Again.')
      turns -= 1          
  else: print('Sorry you are out of turns. You lose, but better luck next time.')
```